# Plotnine Wrap Text in Facet Wrap

Tags: python, plotnine

I am plotting a faceted plot which has very long labels. I am translating some code from R to python. I am looking to wrap the text of the x-axis over multiple lines. I have shown the R code below.

The R code

```
q <- ggplot() + ...
q + scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 8))
```

Is there an equivalent for this using plotnine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that by using `textwrap` and a custom labeler function.

See here for [examples from Plotnine team on date/time labels](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/miscellaneous-manipulating-date-breaks-and-date-labels.html).

Change the numeric argument (the second one in the function call) to increase/decrease the characters in the wrap.

Example using mpg data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from plotnine import *
from plotnine.data import *

%matplotlib inline

# import textwrap and define the custom function
import textwrap

def wraping_func(text):
    return [textwrap.fill(wraped_text, 5) for wraped_text in text]

# example usage

(
    ggplot(mpg) 
    + geom_bar(aes(x='class'))
    + scale_x_discrete(breaks=mpg['class'].unique().tolist(), labels=wraping_func)
)
```

The output that will give the bar chart but labels are wrapt at the 5th character:

[image: the output that will give the bar chart but labels are wrapt at the 5th character]